# display a changed form on previous form submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I'm trying to display another form when currently displaying form values are submitted to server using ajax

This is my html & ajax code

```
<script>
function getproblem(){
var city=document.getElementById('city').value;
var serve=document.getElementById('service').value;
var service;
var url='insert.php';
var xmlhttp=ajax();
if(xmlhttp){
xmlhttp.open("POST",url);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 &&
xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
service=xmlhttp.responseText;
var div=document.getElementById('form').innerHTML;
div.innerHTML='';
div.innerHTML=service; 
}
}
xmlhttp.send("city="+city+"&service="+serve);
}
}
function ajax(){
var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
XMLHttpRequestObject = new
ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
return XMLHttpRequestObject;
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="runnable.css" />
<!-- Load jQuery from Google's CDN -->
<!-- Load jQuery UI CSS  -->
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<!-- Load jQuery JS -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS  -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- Load SCRIPT.JS which will create datepicker for input field  -->
<script src="script/script.js"></script>
<script>
function populate(selector) {
var select = $(selector);
var hours, minutes, ampm;
for(var i = 600; i <= 1100; i += 30){
    hours = Math.floor(i / 60);
    minutes = i % 60;
    if (minutes < 10){
        minutes = '0' + minutes; // adding leading zero
    }
    ampm = hours % 24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
    hours = hours % 12;
    if (hours === 0){
        hours = 12;
    }
    select.append($('<option></option>')
        .attr('value', i)
        .text(hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm)); 
  }
 }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body >
 <div id="form">
 <form method="post" >
 <select name="city" id="city"      onChange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('service'))">
 <option selected="selected" value="">-- --City-- --</option>
 <option value="jhansi">Jhansi</option>
 <option value="lucknow">Lucknow</option>
 </select>
 <select id="service">
 <option selected="selected" value="">-- --Service-- --</option>
 </select>
 <button onclick="getproblem()" name="proceed" >NEXT</button>
 </form>
 </div>
 <p id="a"></p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is my php file

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');
$db=new db();
$sql=$db->database_initialise();
$city=$_POST['city'];
$service=$_POST['service'];
$service_id=mt_rand();
$query="insert into `service` (`id`,`city`,`service_type`)      values('$service_id','$city','$service')";
$result=$sql->query($query);
if($result===true){
$ui=uigenerator($service_id,$service);
echo $ui;
}
else
echo "Sorry An error occured";
function uigenerator($ssid,$service){
$ui='<form method="post" action="next.php?ssid='.$ssid.'"  onload="populate(#timeSelect)"><input type="text" id="problem" value="What\'s    Your Problem" onfocus="document.getElementById(\'problem\').value=\'\' " />';
if($service=='AC Repair/Service'||$service=='Washing Machine Repair'||$service='Refrigerator Repair/Service'|| $service=='Television Repair'){
    $ui=$ui.'<input type="text" value="Brand" id="brnd" onfocus="document.getElementById(\'brnd\').value=\'\'">';
    if($service=='Washing Machine Repair')
        $ui=$ui.'<select id="type" name="type"> <option selected="selected" value="">-- Type --</option><option value="Semi-automatic">Semiautomatic</option><option value="Automatic">Automatic</option></select>';
    else if ($service=="Television Repair")
        $ui=$ui.'<select id="type" name="type"><option selected="selected" value="">-- Type --</option><option value="CRT">Flat screen</option><option value="LCD">LCD</option><option value="LED">LED</option></select>';
}
$ui=$ui.'<input type="text" id="datepicker"  value="Date" onfocus="document.getElementById(\'datepicker\').value=\'\'" /> <select id="timeSelect"><option selected="selected" value="">Time</option></select><input type="submit" name="next" value="Proceed" /></form>';
return $ui;
}
```

when form is submitted and details are logged in database then the new form should be displayed and previous one should be removed.

the problem is that the new form is not shown instead the old form with reset values is shown

Actually when i looked in console to debug it and put the `responsetext` in another element then it was shown but then the page was automatically refreshed to the starting page

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning *document.getElementById('form').**innerHTML*** to the variable *div*. Then you are trying to assign again to the attribute *innerHTML* which would give **innerHTML.innerHTML**.

```
var xmlhttp=ajax();
if(xmlhttp){
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { 
            service=xmlhttp.responseText;
//          var div=document.getElementById('form').innerHTML;
            var div=document.getElementById('form');
            div.innerHTML='';
            div.innerHTML=service; 
        }
}
    xmlhttp.send("city="+city+"&service="+serve);
}
```

Comment: Still same problem after removing that mistake